# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - "Xamarin Update Available" Popup

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I installed Xamarian and have the most recent version of Visual Studio.  Every time I open a project that uses Xamarin, I get this message box:

[image]

No matter where I click on it, it never takes me to the update page.
1) Do I really need an update?
2) If not, how can I get rid of that dialog box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the icons near your clock, there probably is an Xamarin icon there.

Also if that doesn't work, go to *Tools > Options* and find the 'Xamarin' page. There should be an 'Check now' link there which should give you a dialog with info!

Here you can also decide whether you want to receive stable, beta or alpha updates. Remember to set the same setting in you Mac counterpart if you are using a Mac build machine, as it uses the Mac agent.

[image: Xamarin options]

Whether or not you really need the update is up to you! Check out the release notes and decide if it is worth your while to do the upgrade. As far as I know there isn't a way to get rid of the message without upgrading and I don't think you should want that. The upgrade isn't there for nothing, things are better and fixed!